# Класс String и его методы compareTo() и compareToIgnoreCase()

Tags: java, строки

Методы `compareTo()` и `compareToIgnoreCase()` позволяют сравнивать строки, но они позволяют вычислить насколько одна строка больше другой. Как я понял.

```
        String a = "A";
        String b = "z";

        System.out.println(a.compareToIgnoreCase(b));
        System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
```

Вот что вывел:

> //-25
>    //-57

Не пойму в подробностях как этот методы работают, кто может рассказать?

Comment: Рассказать может [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: "насколько одна строка больше другой" -- это вообще бессмысленная вещь. Строки -- не числа, нельзя сказать что "вот эта строка больше той на двадцать пять". Над строками определено отношение порядка, но нет понятия "разность строк"

Answer (score 2):

Каждый символ строки конвертируются в юникод. Если строки равны - возвращается 0, если та строка, которую ты сравниваешь с другой, лексикографически больше, то возвращается положительное число, если меньше - отрицательное

Comment: лексикографически больше это как понять?

Comment: Лексикографическое сравнение - это сравнивание букв и номера буквы в алфавите. Буква А - первая в алфавите, буква Z - последняя, соответственно и "вес" у них разный. Сравнение идет таким образом, что если первые буквы у строки равны, то сравниваются вторые. Это как в словарях или телефонных книгах, строки "abc" и "zxc" равны по длине, поэтому будут сравниваться по позиции символов в алфавите.

Comment: @PetrIvanov по алфавиту, попросту говоря. Только с учетом спецсимволов и проч, в соответствии с порядком символов в Unicode

Answer (score 1):

Суть работы любого компаратора - вернуть целочисленный результат сравнения объектов.
Зажав клавишу Ctrl и щелкнув по методу в большинстве IDE можно перейти к реализации интересующего нас метода.
Так работает компаратор строк:
(строки уже приведены к виду массивов байтов `byte[]`)

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public static int compareTo(byte[] value, byte[] other) {
    int len1 = value.length;
    int len2 = other.length;
    int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);
    for (int k = 0; k < lim; k++) {
        if (value[k] != other[k]) {
            return getChar(value, k) - getChar(other, k);
        }
    }
    return len1 - len2;
}
```

Он поэлементно сравнивает символы от первого и до конца наиболее короткой строки. Если находится пара отличающихся символов, то возвращается результат сравнения первой такой пары. Если все символы совпадают, то возвращается результат сравнения длин строк.